# Can someone please help me by translating this vertical group of Chinese characters and the smaller chop located on the left?

Tags: simplified-characters, seal

These characters are located beneath an antique (19th century?) Chinese ceremonial box that I own. Your help will be greatly appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Left: "……合兴号". (合興號)
I just found a bowl from the period of the Republic of China. The buttom said: 仁重興號. I speculated that it might represent a certain era name. But I didn't found any era names match it. I really don't know what is that mean.

Right: "恒五六".  simplified "石又". It comes from Kangxi Dictionary.

[image]

It does not give out specifical means. It might just mean stone. Because "石" was also a unit of measurement in ancient China, especially for grain. 1 "stone" = 29.95 kg. So I guess "恒五六"just like "五谷丰登"：Abundant harvests.

Comment: Thanks you for your efforts Purple.  Does anyone else have a little more insight for the interpretation of this script?

Comment: Is there anything at the bottom? I don't see it.